# Go-Ethereum "transaction type not supported" Error When Fetching Blocks on BaseChain

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm working with Go-Ethereum (Geth) to interact with the **Base** blockchain, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to fetch block information using the BlockByNumber method. My code is straightforward:

```
block, err := consts.Web3ClientHTTP.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), big.NewInt(oldBlockNum))
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Error fetching block", oldBlockNum, err)
}
```

However, for certain blocks, this results in an error message:

```
Error fetching block transaction type not supported
```

I'm using Go-Ethereum version [1.13.14], and this issue occurs when I try to fetch recent blocks from the Ethereum mainnet. It seems like the error might be related to the handling of new transaction types introduced in recent **Base** Chain updates.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is updating Go-Ethereum to the latest version the only solution, or are there other workarounds?